# Webscraping in BeautifulSoup is returning an empty list

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to web scrape a table from basketball reference and it returns an empty list. I was hoping someone could help me debug or explain why. The page has many tables but it is the Miscellaneous Stats section in particular. Thanks in advance!

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import time
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as plt
import numpy as np

url = 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2020.html#all_misc_stats'
res = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content,'lxml')

soup.find('div', {'id':'div_misc_stats'})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation isn't wrong for parsing the soup, its just that the particular element you're looking for requires javascript to render. You're probably better off looking for some other source of the data if you can find it.

If you really need THIS data, then you may wish to looking rendering the page first (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049520/web-scraping-javascript-page-with-python) for some inspiration)

From my cursory analysis, it also seems there isn't an external network call made to get the data before rendering it, so it may be elsewhere embeded in the page, as xml/json/etc, although I didn't find it in my search. May be worth checking that before investing in a more compute expensive approach if this is not a one time thing you'll need to scrape.

Answer (score 0):

this website that you want to scrape, is a dynamic website, because of this you can't access to all the data at the first you request to the website, you need to wait for some seconds for rendering javascript and then access to all of the website data, for this solution you can use [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/). read the documentation and download the driver chrome or firefox then use it, I wrote the code that you can access to that table :

```
from selenium import webdriver

import pandas as pd
import os
import time


chromedriver = "driver/chromedriver"
os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chromedriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)

url = 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2020.html#all_misc_stats'

driver.get(url)
time.sleep(15)

soruce = driver.page_source

tables = pd.read_html(soruce)

for table in tables:
    try:
        if 'Arena' in table.columns[25][1]:
            print(table)
    except:
        pass
```

print:

```
                   Rk                    Team                Age  ...                       Arena             Attend.           Attend./G
0                 1.0        Milwaukee Bucks*               29.2  ...                Fiserv Forum              549036               17711
1                 2.0     Los Angeles Lakers*               29.6  ...              STAPLES Center              588907               18997
2                 3.0   Los Angeles Clippers*               27.4  ...              STAPLES Center              610176               19068
3                 4.0        Toronto Raptors*               26.6  ...            Scotiabank Arena              633456               19796
4                 5.0        Dallas Mavericks               26.2  ...    American Airlines Center              682096               20062
5                 6.0         Boston Celtics*               25.3  ...                   TD Garden              610864               19090
6                 7.0        Houston Rockets*               29.1  ...               Toyota Center              578458               18077
7                 8.0              Utah Jazz*               27.5  ...     Vivint Smart Home Arena              567486               18306
8                 9.0         Denver Nuggets*               25.6  ...                Pepsi Center              633153               19186
9                10.0  Oklahoma City Thunder*               25.6  ...     Chesapeake Energy Arena              600699               18203
10               11.0             Miami Heat*               25.9  ...      AmericanAirlines Arena              629771               19680
11               12.0     Philadelphia 76ers*               26.4  ...          Wells Fargo Center              639491               20629
12               13.0         Indiana Pacers*               25.6  ...     Bankers Life Fieldhouse              529002               16531
13               14.0    New Orleans Pelicans               25.4  ...        Smoothie King Center              528172               16505
14               15.0           Orlando Magic               26.0  ...                Amway Center              529870               17093
15               16.0       Memphis Grizzlies               24.0  ...                 FedEx Forum              523297               15857
16               17.0            Phoenix Suns               24.7  ...  Talking Stick Resort Arena              550633               15606
17               18.0  Portland Trail Blazers               27.5  ...                 Moda Center              628303               19634
18               19.0           Brooklyn Nets               26.5  ...             Barclays Center              524907               16403
19               20.0       San Antonio Spurs               27.9  ...                 AT&T Center              550515               18351
20               21.0        Sacramento Kings               27.1  ...             Golden 1 Center              520663               16796
21               22.0  Minnesota Timberwolves               24.8  ...               Target Center              482112               15066
22               23.0           Chicago Bulls               24.4  ...               United Center              639352               18804
23               24.0         Detroit Pistons               25.9  ...        Little Caesars Arena              509469               15294
24               25.0      Washington Wizards               25.4  ...           Capital One Arena              532702               16647
25               26.0         New York Knicks               24.5  ...  Madison Square Garden (IV)              620789               18812
26               27.0       Charlotte Hornets               24.3  ...             Spectrum Center              478591               15428
27               28.0     Cleveland Cavaliers               25.0  ...         Quicken Loans Arena              643008               17861
28               29.0           Atlanta Hawks               24.1  ...            State Farm Arena              545453               16043
29               30.0   Golden State Warriors               24.4  ...                Chase Center              614176               18064
30                NaN          League Average               26.2  ...                         NaN              575820               17788

[31 rows x 28 columns]
```

Answer (score 0):

The data is inside HTML comment `<!-- ... -->`. You can use this script to load it inside a DataFrame:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment


url = 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2020.html'

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')
table = soup.select_one('h2:contains("Miscellaneous Stats")').find_next(text=lambda t: isinstance(t, Comment))

df = pd.read_html(str(table))[0].droplevel(0, axis=1)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
      Rk                    Team   Age     W     L  PW  PL    MOV   SOS    SRS   ORtg   DRtg  ...    TS%   eFG%  TOV%  ORB%  FT/FGA   eFG%  TOV%  DRB%  FT/FGA                       Arena  Attend.  Attend./G
0    1.0        Milwaukee Bucks*  29.2  53.0  12.0  52  13  11.29 -0.85  10.44  112.6  101.9  ...  0.583  0.553  12.8  20.7   0.196  0.486  12.2  81.7   0.172                Fiserv Forum   549036      17711
1    2.0     Los Angeles Lakers*  29.6  49.0  14.0  45  18   7.41  0.34   7.75  113.0  105.6  ...  0.577  0.548  13.2  24.6   0.196  0.509  13.8  78.4   0.202              STAPLES Center   588907      18997
2    3.0   Los Angeles Clippers*  27.4  44.0  20.0  44  20   6.52  0.22   6.74  113.6  107.2  ...  0.574  0.532  12.7  24.0   0.232  0.503  12.3  77.3   0.210              STAPLES Center   610176      19068
3    4.0        Toronto Raptors*  26.6  46.0  18.0  44  20   6.45 -0.57   5.88  111.6  105.2  ...  0.574  0.536  12.8  21.6   0.205  0.502  14.6  76.1   0.200            Scotiabank Arena   633456      19796
4    5.0        Dallas Mavericks  26.2  40.0  27.0  45  22   6.04 -0.21   5.84  116.7  110.6  ...  0.581  0.548  11.3  23.5   0.198  0.519  10.9  77.4   0.172    American Airlines Center   682096      20062
5    6.0         Boston Celtics*  25.3  43.0  21.0  44  20   6.17 -0.48   5.69  112.9  106.8  ...  0.567  0.529  12.0  23.9   0.204  0.510  13.6  77.5   0.212                   TD Garden   610864      19090
6    7.0        Houston Rockets*  29.1  40.0  24.0  39  25   3.75  0.03   3.78  113.8  110.2  ...  0.578  0.539  12.6  22.4   0.226  0.528  13.5  75.6   0.194               Toyota Center   578458      18077
7    8.0              Utah Jazz*  27.5  41.0  23.0  38  26   3.17  0.03   3.20  112.6  109.4  ...  0.587  0.552  13.6  21.2   0.208  0.514  10.9  79.0   0.180     Vivint Smart Home Arena   567486      18306
8    9.0         Denver Nuggets*  25.6  43.0  22.0  39  26   2.95  0.06   3.02  112.5  109.5  ...  0.564  0.532  12.3  24.7   0.178  0.526  13.0  77.0   0.194                Pepsi Center   633153      19186
9   10.0  Oklahoma City Thunder*  25.6  40.0  24.0  37  27   2.45  0.34   2.79  111.6  109.1  ...  0.577  0.534  12.3  19.2   0.233  0.520  12.4  76.8   0.164     Chesapeake Energy Arena   600699      18203
10  11.0             Miami Heat*  25.9  41.0  24.0  39  26   3.23 -0.65   2.58  112.7  109.4  ...  0.587  0.549  13.5  20.5   0.231  0.522  12.3  79.7   0.208      AmericanAirlines Arena   629771      19680
11  12.0     Philadelphia 76ers*  26.4  39.0  26.0  37  28   2.22  0.01   2.22  110.4  108.2  ...  0.562  0.530  12.7  23.7   0.189  0.522  12.7  80.4   0.211          Wells Fargo Center   639491      20629
12  13.0         Indiana Pacers*  25.6  39.0  26.0  37  28   1.94 -0.33   1.61  110.3  108.3  ...  0.565  0.533  11.9  20.3   0.170  0.513  12.8  77.1   0.193     Bankers Life Fieldhouse   529002      16531
13  14.0    New Orleans Pelicans  25.4  28.0  36.0  30  34  -0.83  1.13   0.30  110.8  111.6  ...  0.567  0.538  13.7  24.3   0.183  0.531  12.3  78.1   0.207        Smoothie King Center   528172      16505
14  15.0           Orlando Magic  26.0  30.0  35.0  30  35  -0.97  0.12  -0.85  108.0  109.0  ...  0.540  0.503  11.4  22.4   0.191  0.535  13.5  79.0   0.170                Amway Center   529870      17093
15  16.0       Memphis Grizzlies  24.0  32.0  33.0  30  35  -1.08  0.02  -1.05  109.4  110.4  ...  0.561  0.530  13.2  23.2   0.178  0.520  12.6  77.6   0.213                 FedEx Forum   523297      15857
16  17.0            Phoenix Suns  24.7  26.0  39.0  30  35  -1.37  0.32  -1.05  110.5  111.8  ...  0.572  0.528  13.3  22.2   0.226  0.543  14.0  78.3   0.221  Talking Stick Resort Arena   550633      15606
17  18.0  Portland Trail Blazers  27.5  29.0  37.0  30  36  -1.61  0.49  -1.11  112.5  114.1  ...  0.566  0.530  11.5  22.0   0.191  0.523  11.0  75.0   0.204                 Moda Center   628303      19634
18  19.0           Brooklyn Nets  26.5  30.0  34.0  31  33  -0.64 -0.54  -1.18  108.1  108.7  ...  0.550  0.515  13.4  23.5   0.199  0.507  10.9  77.8   0.181             Barclays Center   524907      16403
19  20.0       San Antonio Spurs  27.9  27.0  36.0  28  35  -1.76  0.57  -1.21  111.9  113.7  ...  0.569  0.529  11.0  19.5   0.206  0.542  11.5  79.2   0.194                 AT&T Center   550515      18351
20  21.0        Sacramento Kings  27.1  28.0  36.0  28  36  -1.92  0.48  -1.44  109.7  111.6  ...  0.563  0.531  13.0  21.8   0.178  0.540  13.6  78.5   0.222             Golden 1 Center   520663      16796
21  22.0  Minnesota Timberwolves  24.8  19.0  45.0  24  40  -4.30  0.51  -3.78  108.1  112.2  ...  0.551  0.514  13.0  22.1   0.209  0.541  13.2  77.2   0.218               Target Center   482112      15066
22  23.0           Chicago Bulls  24.4  22.0  43.0  26  39  -3.08 -0.73  -3.81  106.7  109.8  ...  0.547  0.515  13.7  22.8   0.175  0.546  16.3  75.6   0.239               United Center   639352      18804
23  24.0         Detroit Pistons  25.9  20.0  46.0  26  40  -3.56 -0.66  -4.22  109.0  112.7  ...  0.561  0.529  13.8  22.6   0.194  0.541  12.7  75.9   0.186        Little Caesars Arena   509469      15294
24  25.0      Washington Wizards  25.4  24.0  40.0  24  40  -4.05 -0.81  -4.86  111.9  115.8  ...  0.568  0.528  12.1  22.0   0.214  0.560  14.0  74.9   0.230           Capital One Arena   532702      16647
25  26.0         New York Knicks  24.5  21.0  45.0  20  46  -6.45 -0.09  -6.55  106.5  113.0  ...  0.531  0.501  12.6  25.8   0.182  0.541  12.4  78.3   0.224  Madison Square Garden (IV)   620789      18812
26  27.0       Charlotte Hornets  24.3  23.0  42.0  19  46  -6.75 -0.12  -6.88  106.3  113.3  ...  0.539  0.504  13.3  23.9   0.188  0.546  13.1  74.4   0.159             Spectrum Center   478591      15428
27  28.0     Cleveland Cavaliers  25.0  19.0  46.0  18  47  -7.89  0.33  -7.55  107.5  115.4  ...  0.553  0.522  14.6  24.6   0.172  0.560  11.7  77.4   0.164         Quicken Loans Arena   643008      17861
28  29.0           Atlanta Hawks  24.1  20.0  47.0  18  49  -7.97  0.40  -7.57  107.2  114.8  ...  0.554  0.515  13.8  21.6   0.204  0.543  12.7  74.9   0.233            State Farm Arena   545453      16043
29  30.0   Golden State Warriors  24.4  15.0  50.0  16  49  -8.71  0.79  -7.92  105.2  113.8  ...  0.540  0.497  13.2  21.5   0.212  0.553  13.7  76.4   0.193                Chase Center   614176      18064
30   NaN          League Average  26.2   NaN   NaN  32  32   0.00  0.00   0.00  110.4  110.4  ...  0.564  0.528  12.8  22.6   0.199  0.528  12.8  77.4   0.199                         NaN   575820      17788

[31 rows x 28 columns]
```